# Sculpted object turns into a cube when I enter edit mode

Tags: mesh, objects, sculpting

I have just recently sculpted a Mesh Helmet model and I am needing it to export it for another program. When I switch the mesh into edit mode it turns into its original starting cube. Going into sculpt mode again returns it to my helmet. I didn't think it was an issue, but when I exported it into a `.dae` file it came out as the cube instead of the helmet. How do I make the helmet show up correctly in Edit mode and the `.dae` file instead of the cube?

Comment: Try applying any modifiers (`Alt+C`> *Convert To Mesh*)

Comment: @gandalf3 Wouldn't recommend converting the entire thing to a mesh, OP might have other modifiers.

Answer (score 8):

You more than likely have a [*Multiresoultion*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Multiresolution) modifier on your object. You can switch to the *Modifiers* tab and press *Apply* on the modifier to apply this and see how your object looks in edit mode ***but*** if you apply it now, you will lose the ability to adjust any settings on the modifier and you might be left with a really high poly object which is undesirable if you decide to tweak the sculpt later (reduce view levels etc to reduce the load on the viewport).

If you still decide to apply the modifier, I would recommend making a copy of the sculpt just in case.

To keep the modifier and export the sculpt, when using the Collada exporter, look in the properties to the left and tick *Apply modifiers*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have some modifiers on the object.

Try applying them to the mesh data. You can do this either by selecting the object in *Object mode* and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> Mesh*:

[image]

Or by pressing *Apply* on each modifier in *Properties > Modifiers*:

[image]